# Can't get any Workflow from a Threshold List

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, null, workflow, threshold

I have created a script which works fine if a list is not threshold. Provided below is my script:

```
Foreach($ListItem in $List){
    #Get workflows and its properties and traversing each item
    $WorkflowInstance = Get-PnPWorkflowInstance -List $ListName -ListItem $ListItem.Id
    $ListItem
    ForEach($Item in $WorkflowInstance)
    {
        If($Item.FaultInfo){
            $Fault = $(If ($Item.FaultInfo.IndexOf("`n") -gt 0) {$Item.FaultInfo.Substring(0, $Item.FaultInfo.IndexOf("`n"))} Else {$Item.FaultInfo})
        }
        Else{
            $Fault = {}
        }

        $URL = "$($Item.Context.Url)_layouts/15/wrkstat.aspx?List={$($ListItem["GUID"])}&WorkflowInstanceName=$($Item.Id)"
        Add-Content -Path $Path -Value "$($ListItem["Title"]),$($Item.Status),$($Item.UserStatus),$($Item.InstanceCreated),$($Item.LastUpdated),$URL,$($Fault)"
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "$($ListItem["Title"])/$($Item.UserStatus) --- Completed"
    }
}
```

I am not encountering any error but I don't receive any workflows either. I did some debugging and it seems that on `$WorkflowInstance`, `$ListName` has a value and so did `$ListItem.Id`, but `$WorkflowInstance` itself is null. I would like to seek help as I've been struggling for this piece of code for days.

Comment: what do you mean by "if a list is not threshold"?

Comment: Hi Muhammad, when the item count is 4000 or less, the script tends to work. However, when it has a threshold or more than 4000, the script skips the foreach statement because $WorkflowInstance gets null value.

Comment: i guess this is related to list view threshold limit (5000). how are you getting list items? if using CAML query, make sure that column being use as a filter must be indexed, columns being used to filter list views must be indexed and any view in the list must not return more than 5k items.

Comment: Hi again Muhammad, yes, there is a list view threshold limit, and the item is around 4.7k. With regards to fetching items, I'm also using PnP, I tried using CAML query but it also didn't affect the output, and I'll try indexing it before apply CAML query again. Will inform you what happens. Thanks!

Comment: ok and also make sure the views in the list are also filtered by indexed columns and don't return more than 5k items. Then your script should work

Comment: Hi, I have tested the script again with another newly created site. It seems that having item threshold is not an issue. Moreover, it was the site that is having issues with regards to its workflow. Thank you for your help Muhammad.